# Compiling PDCurses into ".a", error with mingw command

Tags: windows-7, mingw, codeblocks, curses, pdcurses

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYnfix8ruAo
for compiling PDCurses and linking it to a CodeBlocks project, but I keep getting an error ('mingw32-make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.)

The thing is, I definitely have mingw installed properly, and have a path pointing to it in the system environment variables.
http://puu.sh/id6nC/3ab670cbdc.png
In the terminal, I tried the command twice without specifying a target file to make sure it's recognized, and it is. It's not until after I get to the point that I want to build the library that it stops recognizing it as a command for some reason. I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a PDCurses issue, it's a `PATH` issue. The `PATH` is an environment variable that the command-line shell uses to locate the executables you type as commands, if they aren't in the current directory, or shell built-ins. It's a list of directories, separated by semi-colons. Each directory is checked in turn, until a match is found.

Specifcally, your problem is this line:

`path=c:\CodeBlocks\mingw\bin`

Apparently, mingw32-make is not in that location. But, since it was found without that line, you clearly don't need the line -- at least not for that. So, just take it out.

Now, if it later turns out that you *do* need to add `\CodeBlocks\mingw\bin` to your `PATH` for some other reason, then the way to do it is like this:

`path=%PATH%;c:\CodeBlocks\mingw\bin`

This appends your new path to the existing `PATH`, instead of wiping out the existing `PATH` and replacing it with that directory alone.